# How to remove dynamic button on android studio

Tags: android

I add some button with image and animation in my code, the following is my code.

```
//add diamond to relativelayout
private void addDiamond(){
    Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.diamond );
    img.setBounds( 0, 0, diamondWidth, diamondHeight );
    for (int i = 0; i < diamondRow; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                diamondHeight+120));
        for (int j = 0; j < diamondCol; j++) {
            Button btnTag = new Button(getContext());
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            btnTag.setCompoundDrawables(null, img, null, null);
            btnTag.setText("0.0158" + (j + 1 + (i * diamondCol)));
            btnTag.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btnTag.setTextSize(8);
            btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * diamondCol));
            btnTag.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
            row.addView(btnTag);
        }
        diamond_lyt.addView(row);
    }
    animate(diamond_lyt);
}

private Button.OnClickListener btnClick = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Button button = diamond_lyt.findViewById(v.getId());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(button.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ViewGroup layout  =  (ViewGroup) button.getParent();
        layout.removeView(button);
    }
};
```

Now I wnat to click these button to remove it individually.
But it is very strange in the result.
When I click two column first button, it remove two column last button.

Please how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You do not need `findViewById()` . Just do `layout.removeView(v);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the click, it removes the views correctly as you click on them. I guess whenever you remove a button, the remaining buttons in the row shift towards left creates an illusion which makes you think it removes the wrong button.

If you intend to have a *grid-like* layout, that the buttons should always stay in their positions on screen, you could try setting the visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` instead of removing the view, or replace it with an empty view of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

This one too simple.....

Instead of this ...

```
private Button.OnClickListener btnClick = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Button button = diamond_lyt.findViewById(v.getId());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(button.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ViewGroup layout  =  (ViewGroup) button.getParent();
        layout.removeView(button);
    }
};
```

Try this one ....

```
   private Button.OnClickListener btnClick = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Button button =((Button)v);
        ((ViewGroup) button.getParent()).removeView(button);
    }
};
```

**When Your button click `onClick(View v)` v give you instance of `button`. TypeCaste from `View` to `Button` and remove it.**